# Is there a simple way to have an 'any' option in a Wordpress posts filter?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to learn PHP to create a filter for my custom post types (floor plans) that can be filtered by a few different custom fields (bedrooms, bathrooms, etc.). I have a simple HTML form with drop-downs for the different fields. The value is then being passed into the wp_query array. What I'm wanting is some way to have an 'Any' field. So rather than selecting '2', '3', or '4' bedrooms from the filter, the user could select 'Any' and then see all floorplans. I'm hoping there's a way to do it so that I can just pass some value into the query and have it work, but if I need to create a new function I could do that too.

This is the code for my filter, as well as the code to query the posts.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">

  <?php
  $field_key_style = "field_5fac80ce68b66"; // <-- Property Style
    $field_style = get_field_object($field_key_style);
    if( $field_style ) { ?>
    <label> Style
      <select name="stylefilter" class="filterdropdown" >
      <option value=""> Any </option>
      <?php
            foreach( $field_style['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                   echo '<option value="' . $k . '"> ' . $v . '</option>';} ?>
    </select></label> <?php
    }
?>
<div>
<label> Bedrooms
  <select name="bedroomsfilter" class="filterdropdown" >
<option value ="*"> Any </option>
<option value ="2"> 2 </option>
<option value ="3"> 3 </option>
<option value ="4"> 4 </option>
<option value ="5"> 5 </option>
  </select></label>
</div>

<div>
  <label> Bathrooms
  <select name="bathroomsfilter" class="filterdropdown" >
    <option value ="all"> Any </option>
    <option value ="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value ="3"> 3 </option>
  </select></label>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">

</form>
```

```
  function misha_filter_function(){
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'floorplans',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
          'relation'        => 'AND',
              array(
                  'key'     => 'style',
                  'value'   => $_POST['stylefilter'],
                  ),
              array(
                  'key'     => 'bedrooms',
                  'value'   => $_POST['bedroomsfilter'],
                  'type'        => 'NUMERIC',
                  'compare' => '='
                  ),
              array(
                  'key'     => 'bathrooms',
                  'value'   => $_POST['bathroomsfilter'],
                  'type'        => 'NUMERIC',
                  'compare' => '='
                  ),
    ),
);

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First, pick a value and use that consistently. Right now you are using both `*` and `all`. Second, check the form value and if it is set to that value, don't use it in your filter at all.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the guidance. I used some conditional logic and it seems to be much closer to what I wanted. Right now i have it showing bedrooms from 0 to 100 if 'any' is selected. Is there a better way to do that? Is there a value that means 'all'? Or maybe I just remove the 'value' line all together?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I removed the value line completely and that looks like it's working! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Answer with some if/else statements:

```
function misha_filter_function(){
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'floorplans',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
          'relation'        => 'AND'));


          //bedrooms
          if ( $_POST['bedroomsfilter'] == 'any')
          {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                       'key' => 'bedrooms'
               );
          } else {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                       'key' => 'bedrooms',
                       'value' => $_POST['bedroomsfilter'],
                       'type' => 'numeric',
                       'compare' => '='
               );
          }

          //bathrooms
          if ( $_POST['bathroomsfilter'] == 'any')
          {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                 'key' => 'bathrooms',
               );
          } else {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                 'key' => 'bathrooms',
                 'value' => $_POST['bathroomsfilter'],
                 'type' => 'numeric',
                 'compare' => '='
               );
          }

          //style
          if ( $_POST['stylefilter'] == 'any')
          {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'style'
               );
          } else {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'style',
                'value'   => $_POST['stylefilter']
               );
          }


    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Instead of `$args['meta_query'][]` try `$args['meta_query']['unique_handle']` that way you can pop/push meta_queries to/from the main meta_query array by their handle rather than relying on arbitrary array-keys

Comment: @admcfajn So something like `$args['meta_query']['bedroomsquery']` and `$args['meta_query']['bathroomsquery']` with a differnet meta_query for each of my filter options?